# USB-C charger only delivery direct power to Macbook even if battery is not full

Tags: battery, charging

I have a USB-C charger 87W which I use for my MacBook Pro 15-inch (2018). It only delivers power to my MacBook but doesn't charge the battery (shows a black icon at the top right-hand corner) even if the battery is not full.

What does this mean in electrical terms (the charger is not providing enough watts? The voltage is wrong?) and what can I do to make the charger charge the battery (eg change the USB-C cable? Change the part that connects to a wall socket? Buy a new charger?)

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not the battery?

Comment: quite sure. different cable resulted in different things

Comment: Remember to include such information in your question, if you want to get the problem solved. Please detail how things were different when you used a different cable.